# Django admin list_filter custom field error

Tags: django

I extended the user with extra option, such as department. But when i try adding filter for the derpartment at the admin panel. It throws this error:

> ERRORS:
>   : (admin.E116) The value of 'list_filter[0]' refers to 'department', which does not refer to a Field.

Refrence to how it looks: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-user

With this addition:

```
class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
inlines = (EmployeeInline, )
list_display = ('username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'get_department')
list_filter = ('department',)

def get_department(self, instance):
    return instance.employee.department
```

List display seems work fine.

Answer (score 4):

User model has relationship with Employee Model so you can access it From user Table with employee field. employee is now the field of user.

```
list_filter = ('employee__department',)
```

employee is the Model.
and department is  the field of Employee.
hopes it should work for you My one is  working below is the screen shot the that.

[image: this is my model Screenshot check it out.]

[image: this is admin screenshot and filters]

[image: and this is the final resutls]

Comment: i have added images just for illustrating purpose just to explained and easy.

Answer (score 2):

You have to specify which model `department` is in.

```
list_filter = ('employee__department',)
```