# Django error: The value of 'list_filter[2]' refers to 'is_active', which does not refer to a Field.?

Tags: python, django

I have a django project, but when I try to run `make migrations`, It is failing with an followingerror :

```
$python manage.py makemigrations
SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
<class 'authorization.admin.UserAdmin'>: (admin.E116) The value of 'list_filter[2]' refers to 'is_active', which does not refer to a Field.
```

and my admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin as BaseUserAdmin

from .models import User_u, user_type


class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('email', 'password', 'name', 'last_login')}),
        ('Permissions', {'fields': (
            'is_active',
            'is_staff',
            'is_admin',
            'groups',
            'user_permissions',
        )}),
    )
    add_fieldsets = (
        (
            None,
            {
                'classes': ('wide',),
                'fields': ('email', 'password1', 'password2')
            }
        ),
    )

    list_display = ('email', 'name', 'is_staff', 'last_login')
    list_filter = ('is_staff', 'is_admin', 'is_active', 'groups')
    search_fields = ('email',)
    ordering = ('email',)
    filter_horizontal = ('groups', 'user_permissions',)


admin.site.register(User_u, UserAdmin)

admin.site.register(user_type)
```

So  I am referring to that field, but system is tellimg that there is not a refer, am I doing it wright?

Comment: `The value of 'list_filter[2]' refers to 'is_active', which does not refer to a Field.` **it is saying is_active is not a field in your model** try removing `is_active` from `list_filter = ('is_staff', 'is_admin', 'is_active', 'groups')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are referring to that field, You have to specify which model its in.

For example,

```
list_filter = ('ModelName__is_active')
```

See [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50953753/django-admin-list-filter-custom-field-error)